# Azure Storage Java SDK Check If Blob exist?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

Using the new V10 SDK, is there a way to check if the blob exist before writing? Or should I set an infinite lease on every file that are successfully uploaded?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists()` method to check for a blob's existence: http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html#exists()

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation you linked is for the legacy sdk not for the "V10", however I guess I will use legacy sdk for now.

Comment: Sorry. Let me check the latest SDK. I am pretty sure there must be something there like this.